# While Loop to subtract

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to use a while loop to subtract from the input and then display the amount of items it could get based on the input. Now it randomly selects Food and in cost i am attempting to get it to match the randomly chosen Food to the List.

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

RandomFood = random.sample(Food, 1)
RFS = str(RandomFood)

while mi >= 0:
    cost = Dict.RFS
    mi = mi - cost
```

I don't see why cost isn't working? But I also have not a clue how to display a variable amount of properties.

Comment: try cost = List[RFS] or cost = List.get(RFS, 0)

Comment: Both `RandomFood` and `RFS` are set exactly *once*; their values do not change with each iteration of your loop, which as written could be replaced with `mi = mi % List[RFS]`.

Comment: ... dont call dicts `List` ... also dont call them Dict .. and read about dict and list. You can no access the elememnts of a dict by `Dict.rfs` ...

Comment: Read:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: I rollbacked your last edit. Please do not "fix" your question.. This invalidates all the time spent by the ppl answering your question. The answers do not match your last edit anymore - If you have a new problem., try to solve it and if need be ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use str(randomfood) randomfood is allready str included list and move it in loop. every time it will be diffrent value

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
Dict = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

while mi >= 0:
    RFS = random.sample(Food, 1)[0]
    cost = Dict[RFS]
    mi = mi - cost
    print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(RFS,cost,mi))
```

Comment: Ok that works great, I added 

`if mi < cost:
        continue`

Under `mi = mi - cost` so it wouldn't purchase it and grant a negative number. But i also want it to check the other numbers to see if those can be purchased instead of hard stopping at say 4 Money left

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
List = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

RandomFood = random.choice(Food)
RFS = str(RandomFood)

while mi >= 0:
    cost = List[RFS]
    mi = mi - cost
```

As @Patrick Artner suggested, `choice()` it's a better choice here (*hah!*).
`List` is a dictionary, to get values from a dictionary one must follow this syntax: `dict[key]`

Comment: no - we use `RandomFood = random.choice(Food)` to get one element.

Comment: Ok from here how would I display each instance of food "purchased"?

Comment: To get _one_ element by random from an iterable you do not use a method that produces potentially multiple unique elements from it as list to use the 1st one - you use the method that simply gives you _one_ element. Read : https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

Comment: Yeah the code currently grabs one element by random, thats why I am asking how do i make it grab a variable amount of elements and then output in print what it has grabbed and how many of each it has grabbed.

Comment: You must change the second parameter of sample then: RandomFood = random.choice(Food, SampleSize). Although with a population of n=3 it's difficult.

Comment: @B14d3r11  it will only ever grab at most one using sample  - random.sample is drawing without putting back. random.choices is drawing with putting back. random.choice is getting 1 from iterable. See documentation - API documentation are really helpful to figure out how stuff works. Also look at the documentation to _see_ how to specify how many things to draw from the iterable

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First, you're converting the sample into a string in a way that will create extra characters around the Food, such as "['Taco']" as opposed to "Taco". You should use RandomFood[0] instead of str(RandomFood).

Second, you are calling the item from the list incorrectly. You should use List[RFS] instead of List.RFS

So you're code should look like this:

```
import random

money = input('Total money: ')
mi = int(money)

Food = ['Taco', 'Burrito', 'Nacho']
Price = [6, 4, 2]
List = {f:p for (f, p) in zip(Food, Price)}

RandomFood = random.sample(Food, 1)
RFS = RandomFood[0]

while mi >= 0:
    cost = List[RFS]
    mi = mi - cost
```